# ESLint error: Possible race condition (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, eslint

I'm getting an ESLint error that tells me that the value I'm trying assign is a possible race condition. I'm unsure what that means. I have only just installed ESLint so I wasn't aware that this was a problem. The app will run and work fine, but having the eslint popping off telling me it's a problem is really bugging me and I'd like to find a solution to fix it.

Here's a screenshot of my current code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty way?

Make your code into one line and disable that line from lint.

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
data.lastMessage = results && results[0] || null;
```